# Error in scheme when using cadr

Tags: scheme

Can anyone clarify what this error means?

```
cadr: expects argument of type <cadrable value>; given (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cadr` means `car` and `cdr`. (i.e,  return the `car` of the `cdr` of a list). Both the following expressions have the same effect:

```
> (car (cdr '(1 2 3 4)))
2
> (cadr '(1 2 3 4))
2
```

`(cadr '(1))` will fail because `(cdr '(1))` evaluates to `null`.

Comment: `(cdr (1))` evaluates to `null`

Comment: `(cdr (1))` evaluates to `Wrong type to apply: 1`  `(cdr '(1))` evaluates to `'()`, which is null in the sense of return `#t` from `null?`.